# Doctrine Criteria mixing up parameters in SQL query

Tags: doctrine, criteria

Have a doctrine criteria that appears to be querying with mixed up parameters unless the association is first eagerly loaded.

The setup is quite simple. I have four entities: User, Business, UserBusiness, and UserBusinessMeta.

Each User can belong to one or more Businesses. Each UserBusiness can also have a list of Meta key/values for the given business. So,

User:

- id: 3

Business:

- id: 2

UserBusiness:

- user_id: 3
- business_id: 2

UserBusinessMeta (in the db there is also a unique constraint on user_id, business_id, key):

- user_id: 3
- business_id: 2
- key: 'foo'
- value: 'bar'

In my UserBusiness entity I have a method called: getFoo which has a criteria as shown below:

```
$criteria = Criteria::create()
->where(Criteria::expr()->eq('key', 'foo'))
->setMaxResults(1);

return $this->meta->matching($criteria)->first();
```

For some reason, when the SQL is created for this criteria, it reverses the business_id and user_id values when setting params so that it's looking for a business_id of 3 and a user_id of 2!

```
SELECT 
t0.user_id AS user_id_1, 
t0.business_id AS business_id_2, 
t0.`key` AS key_3, 
t0.`value` AS value_4, 
t0.id AS id_5,
t0.user_id AS user_id_6, 
t0.business_id AS business_id_7 
FROM user_business_meta t0 
WHERE (t0.`key` = ? AND t0.user_id = ? AND t0.business_id = ?) LIMIT 1

array (size=3)
  0 => string 'foo' (length=11)
  1 => int 2
  2 => int 3
array (size=3)
  0 => string 'string' (length=6)
  1 => string 'integer' (length=7)
  2 => string 'integer' (length=7)
```

However, if I set the UserBusinessMeta association fetch to be EAGER, then the variables are correctly loaded into memory and the above criteria -- not having to use SQL -- returns the right result.

I use XML mapping and there's really nothing special going on in them. The names of the columns and fields are correct as are the associations:

Business -> one-to-many UserBusiness
UserBusiness -> one to many UserBusinessMeta

The mapping for the association here is:

```
 <one-to-many target-entity="UserBusinessMeta" mapped-by="UserBusiness" field="meta" orphan-removal="true">
            <cascade>
                <cascade-persist/>
                <cascade-remove/>
            </cascade>
        </one-to-many>
```

And the user_id and business_id columns are mapped:

```
    <id name="businessId" column="business_id" type="integer" />
    <id name="userId" column="user_id" type="integer" />
```

In UserBusinessMeta the many-to-one association back to UserBusiness is defined as follows:

```
<many-to-one target-entity="UserBusiness" field="UserBusiness" inversed-by="meta">
        <join-columns>
            <join-column name="user_id" referenced-column-name="user_id" />
            <join-column name="business_id" referenced-column-name="business_id" />
        </join-columns>
    </many-to-one>
```

Finally, the UserBusinessMeta entity also has the two columns for business_id and user_id mapped as so:

```
    <field name="userId" column="user_id" type="integer" />
    <field name="businessId" type="integer" column="business_id" />
```

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the issue was due to having two ID's in the UserBusiness entity and one of them needing to be marked as an associate key. the following update fixed it:

```
    <id name="business" column="business_id" type="integer" association-key="true" />
```